# Postgres: Create a self-referencing composite type

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a composite type that has an attribute of the same data type as the composite type I'm creating. I tried doing this through `ALTER TYPE` as such:

```
CREATE TYPE t_mytype AS ( id uuid );
ALTER TYPE t_mytype ADD ATTRIBUTE children t_mytype[];
```

But this raises the error: `composite type t_mytype cannot be made a member of itself`, so is there a way around this?

**NOTE**: This is for logic in a plpgsql function that is manually executed. I want to use the type as an input parameter to the function and then recursively iterate over the structure. I'm not using this custom type or arrays to store data. Comments about normalization and tables and queries and the like are not relevant. My database tables are normalized.

Comment: No, and the whole idea is flawed. Hint: avoid composite types and arrays, use a normalized data model.

Comment: A tree structure can be made with table `(id int, value int, parent_id int)`. Then we can use a recursive query to iterate or aggregate this tree into a string representation.

Comment: Avoid arrays, unless there's really no other option. They break normalization, since they don't conform to even 1NF.

Comment: You could use JSON or some different encoding of the tree structure (e.g. `{path: int[], id: uuid}[]`)